# Change Value of Submit Button in WordPress Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7, submit-button

I need to change the value of this submit button from "Send" to "MyString":

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" wtx-context="A7CF2DEB-43B6-43C4-8572-9624A3E7F524">
```

This code snippet was created in WordPress using Contact Form 7, and I cannot alter it, so unfortunately I can't use getelementbyid.

I tried this  but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-submit").value = 'MyString';
</script>
```

Help!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a clear problem statement (see [mcve]).  Do you have errors in the console? Where do you run this - in the header, or the footer? (It may be that the form doesn't exist when the script runs).  Lastly, `getElementByClassName` returns an _array_ of elements, so at a minimum you'd need to do: `document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-submit")[0].value = 'MyString';`

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough. My code did not produce the required change in the submit button text. The text did not change at all. You'll note below that I found Contact Form 7's intended method for producing the change successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind ... it was absurdly simple.

In the Contact Form 7 editor, I change:

```
[submit "Send"] to [submit "MyString"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were very close! Since `document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-submit")` returns an object, you have to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wpcf7-submit')[0].value = 'MyString';
```

It returns an object, because there could be multiple elements which also include the same class. So in this case with `[0]` you would select the first element with the class `wpcf7-submit`.

Answer (score 1):

Also if some one still having issue with submit button text like me after seeing the sanitycheck.

then must be using submit butto like this.

```
[submit "Submit" class:submit-button]
```

so, simply use it this way will work.

```
[submit class:submitBtn "Submit"]
```

not the diff is put the **"Submit"** text at the end will make it work.